# How to generate assembly schematic file in Altium

Tags: altium

I need some help in generating assembly schematic file like the one below (first image). I managed to create something similar to it (second image), but I couldn't add those component names, values and descriptions beside them. I am using Altium Designer version 17.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do this in PCB.

- In the PCB editor, enable a new mechanical layer.
- Make the part names visible, and change (or copy) them to the new mechanical layer.
- Add any additional notes or graphics on this mechanical layer, as desired.

You can then define a new **Outjob** to produce the desired type of output, with only the layers that you want visible.  Output types include, Gerber, PDF, Hardcopy...